# ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/package.json" not found: not found

Tags: reactjs, docker, github-actions, package.json, docker-build

Hi I am working on Github actios to build react app. Below is the content of react app

```
# Fetching the latest node image on apline linux
FROM node:alpine AS development

# Declaring env
ENV NODE_ENV development

# Setting up the work directory
WORKDIR /my-app

# Installing dependencies

COPY ./package.json /my-app
RUN npm install

# Copying all the files in our project
COPY . .

# Starting our application
CMD npm start
```

Below is folder structure

[image]

I am  using below github actions script to build the image

Below is my matrices file

```
{
"webapp": {
        "name": "webapp",
        "docker-image-name": "ghcr.io/my-org/webapp",
        "dockerfile":"my-app/Dockerfile"
    },
}
```

Below is build step

```
build-and-push-image:
    name: "BUILD: ${{ matrix.name }}"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: prep
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.prep.outputs.matrix)}}
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Log in to the Container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: ${{ matrix.docker-image-name }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image 
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: .
          file: ${{ matrix.dockerfile }}
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

When I run the job I get below error

```
#9 [5/7] COPY ./package.json /my-app
#9 ERROR: "/package.json" not found: not found
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/package.json" not found: not found
Error: buildx call failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/package.json" not found: not found
```

I see package.json exist in the solution but still its throwing error file doesn't exist I am not sure the root cause. Can someone help me to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I changed to COPY ./my-app/package.json /my-app and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the context for docker builds always be the current project by updating your VS settings.

In your your VisualStudio settings (C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json by default) you can change the default:

```
"docker.commands.build": "${containerCommand} build --pull --rm -f \"${dockerfile}\" -t ${tag} \"${context}\"",
```

to

```
"docker.commands.build": "${containerCommand} build --pull --rm -f \"${dockerfile}\" -t ${tag} \"${workspaceFolder}\"",
```